# How to manually fire didChange event listener on UITextView with RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

This is how I defined observer for UITextView using RxSwift:

```
mainView.descriptionTextView.rx.didChange.subscribe { [weak self, mainView] _ in
    self?.viewModel.description.accept(mainView.descriptionTextView.text!)
    self?.updateView()
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And then within unit tests module I need to manually call didChange event on it to check if everything was updated correctly then:

```
view.descriptionTextView.text = "abc"
// for UItextField I would call textField.sendActions(for: .editingChanged)
XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.description.value, "abc")
```

Comment: How would you normally do it with a `UITextView`? That's what you have, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextView uses a delegate to detect text changes. Calling `rx.didChange` installs a delegate and sends a next event every time the system calls it.

So to fake this, you have to call the delegate's method manually... You can access the delegate through the text view itself.

```
class Tests: XCTestCase {
    func test() {
        let example = Example()
        example.example()

        example.mainView.descriptionTextView.text = "abc"
        example.mainView.descriptionTextView.delegate?.textViewDidChange?(example.mainView.descriptionTextView)

        XCTAssertEqual(example.viewModel.description.value, "abc")
    }
}
```

Code to make the above test pass:

```
class MainView: UIView {
    let descriptionTextView = UITextView()
}
class ViewModel {
    let description = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
}

class Example {
    let mainView = MainView()
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func updateView() { }

    func example() {
        mainView.descriptionTextView.rx.didChange
            .subscribe { [weak self, mainView] _ in
                self?.viewModel.description.accept(mainView.descriptionTextView.text!)
                self?.updateView()
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, it seems to be a very tricky answer. I will try it and let you know...

Comment: Tricky? You'd have to do the same thing if you weren't using RxSwift and the production code backing it would be harder to write.